# Python executing expect command unmatching quotes issue: python -c 'os.system("expect -c ...")'

Tags: python, expect

```
python -c 'import os; os.system("/usr/bin/expect -c \'spawn ssh root@localhost; expect \"password:\" { send \"root\r\"}; interact\'")'
```

I am getting unmatched quotes issue (> prompt) when I execute the above command in the CLI

But executing it in a python script rather running in the command line works. Also, the expect script syntax is correct.

How to balance/level the quotes in such scenarios? I would like to understand the trick.
Any online validation check tool available as like regular expression parser checking online?

Comment: why not just `expect -c` without python? and python has [tag:pexpect].

Comment: You are right! But the existing test cases were designed this way and I do not want to introduce any new modules

Comment: Your problem is that the shell, which sees the line first, does not handle `\'` inside single quotes; you would need `'\''`. But the right way to construct such commands is as explained by pynext's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, in shell (I'm using `Bash`), write a correct `expect -c "..."`:

```
[STEP 101] # expect -c "spawn ssh foo@localhost date; expect \"assword:\" { send \"foobar\r\"}; expect eof"
spawn ssh foo@localhost date
foo@localhost's password:
Wed 13 Jan 2021 10:26:53 AM CST
[STEP 102] #
```

<sup>(Here I use double quotes only so it'll be easier to put in single quotes for following `python -c '...'`.)</sup>

Then, write a `python -c 'print(...)'` which would output the previous `expect -c`:

```
[STEP 103] # python -c 'print("""expect -c "spawn ssh foo@localhost date; expect \\"assword:\\" { send \\"foobar\\r\\"}; expect eof" """)'
expect -c "spawn ssh foo@localhost date; expect \"assword:\" { send \"foobar\r\"}; expect eof"
[STEP 104] #
```

Then, replace the `print` with `os.system`:

```
[STEP 105] # python -c 'import os; os.system("""expect -c "spawn ssh foo@localhost date; expect \\"assword:\\" { send \\"foobar\\r\\"}; expect eof" """)'
spawn ssh foo@localhost date
foo@localhost's password:
Wed 13 Jan 2021 10:27:33 AM CST
[STEP 106] #
```

Comment: Thank you `pynexj`. Any reason behind three double quotes around the command?

Comment: its python's smart way to allow double quotes in double quotes. you can try `python -c 'print("abc\"def") '` and `python -c 'print("""abc"def""") '`. python also has `''' ... '''`.

Comment: `pynexj` awesome :) Thanks!